# Proving an Unknown Set of Vectors is Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am struggling to understand a question that requires showing the given information about a set of vectors results in a contradiction.

The following information is given:

V1,...,Vk is a sequence of vectors in R^n and V1 ≠ 0
Suppose Vi does not exist within the span(V1,...,Vi-1) for all i = 2,...,k then the sequence V1,...,Vk is linearly independent.

Given this information I am then asked to prove this statement by contradiction and suppose V1,...,Vk is not linearly independent. I am then given the following information that i is the largest element of {1,2,...,k} such that Xi ≠ 0 and prove that Vi = -(X1/Xi)V1 - ... - (Xi-1/Xi)Vi-1 for i ≥ 2.

The problem I am having with this question is that I cannot understand how to setup a proof for this solution even though so much information is given. I also am lost at how I would show what they are asking when previously questions similar to this have involved a set of vectors with numerical values and you can just see if any of the vectors are linear combinations of the others. I believe I should be focusing on the second statement provided about the vector Vi not existing within the span(V1,...,Vi-1).

There is a followup question which asks to investigate the other possibility however I was hoping to discuss this question and talk about a procedure to on how I should solve this and similar questions as I am not even sure how to apply what I know to this question.

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, what is your definition of linear independence? This will give you a good idea of what will suffice as proof

Comment: What is $X_i$? I think I know, but I want you to write it out, because that may help you in solving the whole problem.

Comment: If the vectors are not independent, then there is some nontrivial linear combination of them that equals the zero vector ("nontrivial" meaning the coefficients aren't all zero). manipulate that equation to get what your hint says, and hence a contradiction.

Comment: Hi thank you for the replies. I believe the definition of linear independence is that the given vectors cannot be a linear combination of each other. Sorry I am unsure what Xi is since reading these comments I have only become more confused somehow.

Comment: @Michael The $X_i$ are, in my oppinion, closely related to the linear combination. Think about what a "linear combination" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll complete your proof. You are supposing $v_i=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$ for some scalars $a_i$ where in the RHS doesn't appear $v_i$, and, if $j>i$, then $v_j$ cant't be expressed as a linear combination of $\{v_1,...,v_n\}\backslash\{v_j\}$. Thus, $a_{j}=0$ for all $j>i$, cause, if it not the case for some $j$, then $v_j$ is linear combination of the other vectors, which contradicts election of $i$. So, $v_i=a_1v_1+...+a_{i-1}v_j+0v_{i+1}+...+0v_n$. But it implies $v_i\in span\{v_1,...,v_{i-1}\}$, which contradicts hypothesis. Then, such $i$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense and I can understand what you have done however I just have a question about how and why you have introduced Vj. Sorry I know my question does not make much sense I guess I am struggling with this problem because normally with these problems we have had vectors with values rather than just V1,..Vn

Comment: $i$ is by definition the greater index in $\{1,...,n\}$ for which his corresponding coefficient is not cero. It means that, for every $j>i$, $a_j\neq 0$.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense now :) Understanding this question much better now